# SQL how to do an average when the cell has a value greater than 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Query that gives an Average of Lunch times between two dates.

```
,AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0,  lunchduration) / (60.0 * 60.0)) as avglunchduration
```

Right now I'm getting a very low average value because it's taking into consideration values = 0, so if in a day the employee didn't go to have lunch then my average is going lower...

> What I need is only to do the average when the "lunchduration" column has a value greater than 0.

Any clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use `NULLIF()`:

```
AVG(NULLIF(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0,  lunchduration) / (60.0 * 60.0), 0))
```

This returns `NULL` if the duration is zero, and NULL values are ignored by `AVG()`.

A more explicit `case` statement is more generalizable:

```
AVG(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0,  lunchduration) > 0
         THEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0,  lunchduration) / (60.0 * 60.0)
    END)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AVG(fields)
FROM tables
WHERE lunchduration > 0
```

Where fields is the fields you want and tables are the tables the fields are in.